# DataTables server-side processing URL too long

Tags: datatables

Is there a way I can stop it from sending all of the columns to the server?

Currently the AJAX request looks like:

> ssp.php?draw=2&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=10&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1448240832750

But it's 5689 characters long. I'm looking for a way to disable all of the column data that isn't necessary. Is this possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can send it via POST instead, so none of those fields will appear on the URL sent to your server. Here's an example from the [docs](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "scripts/post.php",
            "type": "POST"
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 13):

if you use `GET` try to remove unnecessary column.

```
$('#your-table').DataTable({
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: {
    url: 'url-here',
    data: function (data) {
      for (var i = 0, len = data.columns.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (! data.columns[i].search.value) delete data.columns[i].search;
        if (data.columns[i].searchable === true) delete data.columns[i].searchable;
        if (data.columns[i].orderable === true) delete data.columns[i].orderable;
        if (data.columns[i].data === data.columns[i].name) delete data.columns[i].name;
      }
      delete data.search.regex;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: For me, I simply removed the `columns` entry: `ajax: { data: ({columns, ...others}) => others }`

Answer (score 6):

use can suppress unnecessary parameters like way bellow:

```
"ajax":{
        url :"admin/customers/ajax_datatables",
        type: "get",
        data: function ( data) {
            delete data.columns; // <-- too long and not neccessary if you don't use

            //and you can add more data
            data.form_search_params = $("#frm_search").serializeFormJSON();
        },
        error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Use delete to remove the fields you don't want to send. Eg below:

```
"ajax": {
            "url": "yoururl",
            "data": function (d) {
                for (var i = 0, len = data.columns.length; i < len; i++) {
                    delete data.columns[i];
                }
                delete data.search.regex;
                return $.extend({}, d, {
                    "filterOne": $('#mydropdown').val(),
                });

            },
            "type": "GET",
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html
The solution is to use post instead of GET

Answer (score 1):

I did something very similar as @felix, had to make a change in order to make it work with Django 3.2.

```
// Remove unnecessary fields from the request, otherwise the server will return an error:
// Bad Request - Request Line is too large (4328 > 4094)
for (let i = 0, len = data.columns.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  if (!data.columns[i].search.value) delete data.columns[i].search;
  if (data.columns[i].searchable === false) delete data.columns[i].searchable;
  if (data.columns[i].orderable === false) delete data.columns[i].orderable;
  if (data.columns[i].data === data.columns[i].name) delete data.columns[i].name;
}
```

The difference is this:

@felix solution:

```
data.columns[i].searchable === true
```

My change:

```
data.columns[i].searchable === false
```

This is because I'm using djangorestframework-datatables and it make it default=False:

https://github.com/izimobil/django-rest-framework-datatables/blob/fab94a9e3d26bd6e393e341cb84d99a406b27db1/rest_framework_datatables/filters.py#L57